# Position div beneath a div that has position absolute

Tags: html, css

I want to make a header with a image in it that will use the whole width of the browser even when zoomed out. Directly under that #slider-wrapper with the image in it is the #main-content. But that div is postioned directly after #topheader now as you can see what indicates my problem. That div must be right after the #slider-wrapper (and thus ) but because #slider-wrapper is positioned absolute, the div #main-content is positioned after #topheader.

How can I get the #main-content positioned after the #slider-wrapper? Is there some other way to make the header image use the whole width of the screen instead of position absolute? Please help me with this, trying this for hours now.

I have made a `jsfiddle` for the first time that's not 100% correct but it will do I think. So atm the header image is using the whole screen even after zoomed out but I can't get the #main-content positioned well. Thanks alot

```
https://jsfiddle.net/hj28fuw7/4/embedded/result/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hj28fuw7/4/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, I think what you need to do is set a top margin on the #main-content to the value of the height of the #slider-wrapper. i.e.

change:

```
#main-content {
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000000;  
}
```

to:

```
#main-content {
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 426px auto 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Already tried it but when you zoom out the div floats upwards again